# document.getElementsByName not working for dynamiv values from radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch the value from radio button tag in HTML to javascript, every time I am trying to do so, i am getting the length of radio button as 0 and return value is undefined. Here, is my code snippet(value is dynamic

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>
   What color do you prefer?<br>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red"    onclick="check();">Red<br>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" id="green"  onclick="check();">Green<br>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" id="yellow" onclick="check();">Yellow<br>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue"   onclick="check();">Blue<br>
</form>
<script>
function check()
{
   var isChangeReqd=getRadioButtonValue(document.getElementsByName("colors"));
}
function getRadioButtonValue(radioObj)
{
   var value;
   var radioLength=radioObj.length;
   alert(radioLength); //is 0 //for value 

   for(var i=0;i<radioLength;i++)
   {
      if(radioObj[i].checked) return radioObj[i];
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying id of the radio instead of name of the radio buttons. 
use `document.getElementsByName("colors")` instead `document.getElementsByName("red")`

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red"    onclick="check();">Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="green"  onclick="check();">Green<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="yellow" onclick="check();">Yellow<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors"id="blue"    onclick="check();">Blue
</form>
<script>
function check()
{
   var isChangeReqd=getRadioButtonValue(document.getElementsByName("colors"));
}
function getRadioButtonValue(radioObj)
{
   var value;
   var radioLength=radioObj.length;
   alert(radioLength); //is 0 //for value 

   for(var i=0;i<radioLength;i++)
   {
      if(radioObj[i].checked) return radioObj[i];
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: removing alert won't help I guess.

Comment: i think this is your solution to your problem . what is the problem?

Comment: @user7455856 isn't this answer sufficient?

Comment: my problem is "isChangeReqd" is coming as "undefined" and length is coming as "0". I am trying to fetch "value" dynamically from java. This code works perfectly fine when i have "value" attribute defined in html

Comment: that is another problem. for this OP this is the answer.

Comment: that is not so @Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on the [Document.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) function will be helpful. Along with the other answers, it looks like you may want to return the value of the radio by calling into elements "id" property, like so: `if(radioObj[i].checked) value=radioObj[i].id ;`
Here is a working example of what I believe you are looking to do.

```js
function check()
{
var isChangeReqd=getRadioButtonValue(document.getElementsByName("colors"));
alert(isChangeReqd);
}

function getRadioButtonValue(radioObj) {
var value;
var radioLength=radioObj.length;
alert(radioLength);//is 0//for value

    for(var i=0;i<radioLength;i++)
    {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) value=radioObj[i].id ;
    }
    return value;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>What color do you prefer?
<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" onclick="check();">Red<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="green" onclick="check();">Green<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="yellow" onclick="check();">Yellow<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors"id="blue"onclick="check();">Blue
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: value is coming as undefined and radioLength=0

Comment: Interessting. Running this code snippet on Chrome returns the iteration number as well as the value of id.

Comment: I am using struts like framework, where radio button "value" and "id" i am getting from java. While using document.getElementsByName i am getting radio button value as "undefined" and "length=0". I can see same code is working when i give value and id attribute statically i.e. simply while defining radio tag.